# How to get AWS Billing metrics through JAVA API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I had found the AWS cloud watch collects Billing metrics, but couldn't find any api references to use them programmatically. I want them as metrics just like Volume metrics, Instance metrics but not as CSV format in S3 bucket. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Billing metrics can be collected just like any other cloud watch metrics: http://i.imgur.com/gKC5XXC.png

Comment: Where can I get that dialogue box to edit the aws configuration ? I have searched a lot but couldn't get.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/billing-metricscollected.html  - cloudwatch billing API description.

Comment: I have checked the documnetaion .This may be very trivial,but I am not able to find relevant information to edit AWS configuration. Can you tell me the steps I can get to that screen you shared ?

Comment: From what I have understood, the screen you shared is from Axibase product. I want to edit from aws console management

Comment: There is nothing on the screenshot that indicates product name. How did you figure it out. Anyway, the reason I shared the screenshot is to provide proof that couldwatch billing metrics and statistics can be exported with standard cloudwatch api calls, just like any other metrics domain on the screenshot. There is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, two things to keep in mind:

1. According to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient.html) documentation, the maximum number of data points returned from a single GetMetricStatistics request is 1,440. So you can't for example, query data from a week in periods of 5 minutes (cause that will be 2,016 datapoints).
2. To get the billing metrics you can request the total of estimated charges across all services or the estimated charges per service. As stated [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/billing-metricscollected.html).

This Java 8 sample, retrieves the total of estimated charges across all services for the last two weeks in periods of twelve hours.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.Datapoint;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.Dimension;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.GetMetricStatisticsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.GetMetricStatisticsResult;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;

public class AWSCloudWatchBillingService { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String awsAccessKey = "<YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY>";
        final String awsSecretKey = "<YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>";

        final AmazonCloudWatchClient client = client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
        final GetMetricStatisticsRequest request = request(); 
        final GetMetricStatisticsResult result = result(client, request);
        printIt(result);   
    }

    private static AmazonCloudWatchClient client(final String awsAccessKey, final String awsSecretKey) {
        final AmazonCloudWatchClient client = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey));
        client.setEndpoint("http://monitoring.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/");
        return client;
    }

    private static GetMetricStatisticsRequest request() {
        final long twoWeeks = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15;
        final int twelveHours = 60 * 60 * 12;
        return new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            .withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - twoWeeks))
            .withNamespace("AWS/Billing")
            .withPeriod(twelveHours)
            .withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("Currency").withValue("USD"))
            .withMetricName("EstimatedCharges")
            .withStatistics("Average", "Maximum")
            .withEndTime(new Date());
    }

    private static GetMetricStatisticsResult result(
            final AmazonCloudWatchClient client, final GetMetricStatisticsRequest request) {
         return client.getMetricStatistics(request);
    }

    private static void printIt(final GetMetricStatisticsResult result) {
        Collections.sort(result.getDatapoints(), (Datapoint dp1, Datapoint dp2) -> dp1.getTimestamp().compareTo(dp2.getTimestamp()));
        System.out.println("**************************************"); 
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```